# Is there a simpler way to check if multiple files have been modified?

Tags: powershell

I am working on a project with around 40 script files and I am going to package the scripts to distribute them to my clients (kind of like a version release). I don't want my clients to change my scripts (at least make it hard for them to change).

I have made certain files Read Only by setting the execution policy but the clients can simply set it back to writable so I want to add in **a few lines of code** (preferably less than 5) to check that the scripts are not modified.

I am aware of using property `LastWriteTime` will do it but I will need to do this for each of the script (a hash table to keep track of the `LastWriteTime` for each file will be to long and not clean enough) which is not ideal.

I have also considered `Get-FileHash` but I am concerned about the hash code will change each time I run it.

Comment: As you have mentioned, `Get-FileHash` is the right wat ro do it. But the hash doesnt change unless the targetted file changes

Comment: Is there a way to get one line of hash code instead of getting a hash code for each file?

Comment: Hashes are normally for files and it is obvious from te name Get-`FileHash`

Comment: Another option would be to use a code signing certificate to digitally sign the script. If they alter the file it will no longer validate as being the script you created. You could then set the execution policy to remotesigned or allsigned. If they alter the file it would then fail to run. Ultimately once the script is in their hands, you can't really prevent them from altering it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already have realized, it is impossible to prevent clients from modifying scripts in water-tight a way. Bruce Schneier sums it up nicely: *"Trying to make bits uncopyable is like trying to make water not wet."*

To run a script, one needs to copy it at least in system's memory - and at that point you've lost control. What's to prevent copying the script in alternate a location and editing it before running? Nothing, unless you have tight control on client. Should you have tight control, setting execution policy to signed prevents running unsigned scripts. Until the client starts Powershell from command line with `-Executionpolicy Bypass` switch. [The execution policy isn't a security system that restricts user actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-6) .

There are a few approaches that can hinder editing, but a determined hacker can overcome those. So the root question is: why? Why shouldn't the clients modify the scripts? Is it to protect some IP? Are they trying to achieve something the scripts are not designed to? Something else?

A simple solution is to use a tool like PS2EXE that converts Powershell script as an executable. The contents can be extracted and modified, but it requires at least a bit more effort than running Notepad.

Another approach would be modules. Distribute the scripts as a Powershell module that the clients will import. Editing a module requires a bit more effort than editing a simple script file, but is quite possible too.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas! The goal is to prevent them from achieving something the scripts are not designed to. The the suggestions are making them into `*.exe`, distributing them as module, creating hash code for them and signing the script. Which approach would you say the hardest for the clients to change?

Comment: @JiaHao All "solutions" are just speed bumps and cannot really stop determined people. What you really need to do is to remove users' incentive for script modification. That is, find out why modifications are desired and provide controlled solutions for those issues. Tech isn't answer to social problems.

Comment: "Tech isn't answer to social problems" - touche